# Secure APIM APIs using Azure Active Directory without login page

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-api-management

We have a project hosted in Azure, exposing APIs via APIM to Desktop web browsers. APIs are secured and only accessible to the company's employees, via Azure AD.

Is it possible to prevent the login page from showing up when users request a resource page? Please see the question at the bottom.

**Update**
Please see my step-by-step based on @SureshBabu-MT's answer:

Step 1: entered the URL below into a web browser

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xx/oauth2/authorize?    
client_id=xx
redirect_uri=https://xxx.developer.azure-api.net/signin-oauth/code/callback/user-authorisation-via-oauth2
response_type=code
state=xxx
scope=
sso_reload=true
prompt=none
```

Response:

```
You have successfully authenticated.
Close <- a button, but the browser tab is not closed after clicking it.
```

Step 2: Entered the target url below:

```
  https://xx-dev.azure-api.net/echo/resource
```

Result:

```
{
statusCode: 401,
message: "Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid."
}
```

It seems the access token is missing from the request in Step 2.

Just to **re-iterate**:

Is it possible that when users enter a target URL like in step2 above, and users get authenticated, and the requested URL returns successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Use Prompt Parameter Function:

OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant can be used in apps that are installed on a device to gain access to protected resources, such as web APIs

The flow enables apps to securely acquire access_tokens that can be used to access resources secured by the Microsoft identity platform

prompt=None (it will ensure that the user isn't presented with any interactive prompt)

GET /authorize?...&prompt={none}&

none - no show login or consent

```html
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
&prompt=none
&login_hint=myuser@mycompany.com
```

The prompt parameter can be used by the **Client** to make sure that the End-User is still present for the current session or to bring attention to the request.

Prompt value is set to none with any other value it gives an error.
The prompt=none parameter causes Auth0 to immediately send a result to the specified redirect_uri (callback URL) using the specified response_mode with one of two possible responses: success or error.

Example:

```html
curl -v -k -X GET "https://localhost:9444/oauth2/authorize?

prompt=none+login&scope=openid..."
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: Thanks for your info. For the second reference on AAD B2C, we don't use B2C, so I guess it is irrelevant?

Comment: Can you confirm that the first reference is this link? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: APIM exposes APIs, End users use those links directly in their web browsers. Is there a way to add `prompt=None` on behalf of the end users? So they don't have to add them manually.